# OpenSSL - How to get buffer length from cipher structures since 1.1 version

Tags: openssl, upgrade

I am using `buf_len` variable member to know what should be the required length if something gets wrong and return to the caller.

```
DecryptUpdate(unsigned char* pEncryptedPart, unsigned long int ulEncryptedPartLen,
    unsigned char* pPart, unsigned long int *pulPartLen){

    unsigned long required_rest = (ctx.buf_len + ulEncryptedPartLen) % EVP_CIPHER_block_size(mCipher);
    unsigned long required_len = ctx.buf_len + ulEncryptedPartLen - required_rest;

    if (pPart == NULL_PTR || *pulPartLen < required_len)
    {
        *pulPartLen = required_len;
        return pPart == NULL_PTR  ? CK_OK : CK_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL;
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I get the buffer length from the cipher structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your mean for the EVP_CIPHER_CTX type.  There is no way to extract this information any longer as it's internal implementation detail.

You will have to keep your own accounting of this information yourself, it's easy enough to calculate based on the data size you are passing in.